# Polycounts are automatically increasing in blender. please help

Tags: modeling

[image]

While I was modeling an object I duplicated some of the stuffs in it and then also some of the bezier paths also got duplicated, but after sometime my polycounts and duplications of the same stuffs started increasing automatically as if someone would have put a virus in my pc. I might have pressed some wrong keys by mistake. If anyone has any idea about it, please do suggest. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go into *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>W</kbd> to open up the specials menu and select *Remove Doubles*.

Otherwise see if reopening your blend file helps: Save it of course (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and select the blend file from that menu.